# Troubles playing sound files using android app development

Tags: android

I am a newbie to Android Development, and I'm having a problem getting my code to implement and actually play a sound file. I suspect that it may due to a problem in my code, however I've looked it over a lot, and I have no idea what could be causing the problem. 
Thanks, Anne

```
package com.mediaplayer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.R.raw;
public class PlayPlayer extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    private MediaPlayer mp;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Button button1 = (Button) this.findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnTouchListener(this);
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
            mp.start();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mp.setLooping(true);
            mp.start();

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            mp.pause();
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I've never used audio in Android, and assuming that the resource is correct (R.raw.music) you have a problem in the switch (no breaks) it should look like this:

```
switch (event.getAction()) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        mp.pause();
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I tried that and it still doesn't play the sound file. I wonder if it could be due to the fact that I'm using a touch screen function instead of click function, although I have the touch screen emulator package installed on my avd.

Comment: Can you use debug an see if the onTouch method gets called